# What value does a call to printf() produce?

Tags: c, printf

In my programming class, I don't understand what the value of `printf("World")` is (question my prof is asking)?  What value does `printf` return?  He says it is 5, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are talking about C or C++? Then [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) you will find the answer:

> On success, the total number of characters written is returned.

Answer (score 6):

Because [`printf()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html#tag_03_180_04) returns the number of bytes that were output. For "World", that's 5: 5 characters, 5 bytes. Count 'em...

When you're learning a new language, it's always a good idea to read the documentation for the new functions you're learning how to use. If you follow the link above, you'll find the following documented for the return value of *printf()*:

> Upon successful completion, the fprintf() and printf() functions shall return the number of bytes transmitted.

If your professor is asking you this question, you'll probably find that this was documented in the class textbook as well. *Read* it, *learn* it, *love* it!

Comment: Excellent idea, **read** the documentation. Now I'm wrestling with the idea of upvoting the question. I think it was clear and useful, even if the OP hasn't *engaged* with the idea of SO in the last 2 months.

Comment: @pavium: Are you considering the user rather than content for voting? For shame. :)

Comment: Yes, I know. I try to resist, but sometimes I fail. Mea Culpa.

Answer (score 1):

Remember... these are different things:
  What will printf *PRINT*.
  What will printf *RETURN*.

The function will *RETURN* "the number of bytes" that it output.

It might *PRINT* the word "duck" on your screen.
... but it will *RETURN* the number 4.  (It wrote 4 characters.)